# Android 13 : Why do we still need to include POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission in AndroidManifest.xml for Foreground service purpose?

Tags: android

Based on https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission

> Note: Apps don't need to request the POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission in
> order to launch a foreground service. However, apps must include a
> notification when they start a foreground service, just as they do on
> previous versions of Android.

My requirement is that, I need to start a foreground service, with notification UI visible (Because the notification UI will contain UI control to pause/ stop the foreground service)

In Android 13, the following function returns false by default.

> If a user installs your app on a device that runs Android 13 or
> higher, your app's notifications are off by default.

```
public static boolean areNotificationsEnabled() {
    Context context = Application.instance();

    final boolean areNotificationsEnabled = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).areNotificationsEnabled();

    return areNotificationsEnabled;
}
```

To ensure it returns true, I need to launch `Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS` activity to prompt user to turn on manually.

### Code to launch Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS

```
public static void launchActionAppNotificationSettings(Fragment fragment, int requestCode) {
    try {
        fragment.startActivityForResult(getLaunchActionAppNotificationSettingsIntent(fragment.getContext()), requestCode);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "", e);
    }
}

private static Intent getLaunchActionAppNotificationSettingsIntent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = null;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);

        intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, context.getPackageName());
    } else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        intent = new Intent("android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS");

        intent.putExtra("app_package", context.getPackageName());
        intent.putExtra("app_uid", context.getApplicationInfo().uid);
    } else {
        intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);

        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));
    }

    return intent;
}
```

### UI for Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS

[image]

Please take note on the button in red circle.

I realize, if I do not include `POST_NOTIFICATIONS` permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`, I am not able to turn on the button, even though I have clicked on it multiple time.

Seems like, even we do not request `POST_NOTIFICATIONS` permission during runtime, we still need to include it in `AndroidManifest.xml`, for Foreground service purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android 13 introduced a new [Task Manager](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-all#fgs-manager) (same idea as Windows' Task Manager), which basically makes the foreground service notification obsolete by making sure the user is aware you're operating in the background.

This is why [Android 13 allows foreground service notification to be dismissible](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#user-dismiss-notification) and [Android 14 forces all notifications to be dismissible](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-all#non-dismissable-notifications).

The new Task Manager have built-in ability to stop your foreground service so don't mind losing the "Stop" action for your foreground service.

So, to your question.
Since Android 13:

1. To use foreground service notification, you must add `POST_NOTIFICATIONS` to manifest (not necessarily granting it).
2. You can use foreground service without notification permission. Calling `startForeground(...)` will not show notification, but your background operation will still be reflected to the user with the new Task Manager.

I'll double check this whole thing today to make sure I'm correct

Comment: What if showing the notification UI is a "must" requirement? In such a case, we must make sure `areNotificationsEnabled` is true. But, what is a appropriate flow, to ensure `areNotificationsEnabled` is true? Should we bring users to `Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS` page for them to enable manually, or shall we prompt for `POST_NOTIFICATIONS` runtime permission?

Comment: Runtime permission is the best experience (it actually controls the same switch from notifications settings). Since Android 13 - I recommend ditching the notifications settings entirely and check/request permission only via `POST_NOTIFICATIONS` runtime permission

Comment: Well I don't find any Task Manager on Samsung devices running Android 13 or Android 14 :) So maybe it's available only on Pixel and mb other devices